# How to reverse the order of lines?

Tags: rearrangement

How can I reverse the order of lines so that the first line appears at the end and the last line appears first?  (Could be all the lines in a buffer, an address range, or a linewise visual mode selection.)

I'd like to transform

```
rat
ox
tiger
⋮
dog
pig
```

into

```
pig
dog
⋮
tiger
ox
rat
```

without resorting to an external command such as `tac`.

Comment: Any suggestions for better tags on this question?

Comment: maybe a new 'pure-vi' or similar tag? I've seen several questions that would benefit from a tag that would indicate a desire to have no external tools involved. Should I ask about that on Meta?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker (and anyone else interested in following this) the tag question is now on meta http://meta.vi.stackexchange.com/questions/1229/should-we-have-a-tag-to-indicate-a-question-doesnt-want-external-tools-involed

Answer (score 40):

The power of global  will work here:

```
:g/^/exe "normal ddggP"
```

Or, more simply (thanks @tommcdo)

```
:g/^/move 0
```

The first will match every line and for each line, delete it and paste it to the top of the file. As it moves through the file, it reverses the text.

The second similarly matches every line and moves it to the top of the file.

**Note:** Both of these work on the *whole file* and will not apply correctly to reversing a subset of the lines. See [Ingo Karkat's answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/2107/227) for a solution that works within a range.

Description:

`g` global command
`/^/` match any line that has a beginning (i.e. all lines)
`exe` execute the following string
`"normal` perform normal mode commands
`dd` delete line
`gg` move to top of file
`P` paste above current position

`move 0` moves the current line to below line 0 (which puts it at position 1, or the first line of the file)

Comment: Instead of the `:normal` command, we can use the Ex command `:move 0`, which moves the line to the beginning of the buffer.

Comment: Also `:execute` is only necessary when the command needs to be built dynamically, e.g. `:execute 'normal' g:user_command`.

Comment: @tommcdo good points! I'm in the habit of using `:execute` because I often end up appending other Ex commands after the existing one later, and it's more convenient for me to have the `:exe` there already than to have to go back and insert it later. Unfortunately, that habit leaked into this answer where it doesn't apply as much.

Comment: More explanation about my use of `:execute`: since it takes a string, it provides a clear delineation for where the normal-mode commands end, even though I'm not constructing the string, it's easier for me to find balanced quotation marks than to look for `<esc>` or whatever to terminate the mode. Again, this is personal preference and habit. :-)

Comment: Note this only works on the entire buffer ... Something like `:7,8g/^/move 0` does strange things...

Comment: Very true. I'll make note of that in the answer. I didn't make it a subset because 200_success explicitly called out first and last lines.

Comment: This will work for a range btw: `:9,11g/^/move 8` ... The last number needs to be the start of the range minus 1 (adapted from Ingo's answer).

Comment: And, now I see I misread part of the question, he did call out ranges and selections.

Answer (score 14):

This one-liner (for your `~/.vimrc`) defines a `:Reverse` command; you can also use the `:global` part directly, but the syntax of the `:move` (which iteratively shifts the lines to before the start of the range, thereby reversing it) isn't easy to memorize:

```
:command! -bar -range=% Reverse <line1>,<line2>global/^/m<line1>-1
```

Comment: As a FYI for readers, the `<line1>` & `<line2>` are required to make this work on a range, ie: `:7,9Reverse` (they're features of `command`, not `global` or `move`). The simpler `:command! -bar -range=% Reverse :global/^/m 0` will also work, but only for the entire buffer...

Answer (score 8):

Pure Vim:

```
:g/^/m0
```

Explanation:

> According to `:help multi-repeat`, `:g` and its cousin `:v` work in a two-pass manner.
>
> The first pass of `:g` marks every line matching `{pattern}`, while the second pass (apparently performed starting at the file's beginning and proceeding to the end) performs the `[cmd]`. The above use of `:g` takes advantage of the order the lines are processed in (which is probably okay, though probably not technically guaranteed).
>
> It works by first marking every line, then moving the first marked line to the top of the file, then moving the second to the top of the file (above the line moved previously), then the third marked line (again above the previously moved line), and so on until the last line in the file is moved to the top, effectively reversing the file.
>
> Note that if `:g` processed lines in any order other than from top to bottom, this command would not work.

Source: [Reverse all lines](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Reverse_all_lines) and [Power of g](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Power_of_g) at vim wikia.

Few examples using external commands:

- `tac` (part of [GNU coreutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/) - `cat` reversed):

  ```
  :%!tac
  ```
- `tail` on BSD/OSX (not POSIX-compliant):

  ```
  :%!tail -r
  ```

  > `-r`      The -r option causes the input to be displayed in reverse order, by line.
  >
  > Check: `man tar` for more details.

For more ideas, see:

- [How can I reverse the order of lines in a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742466/how-can-i-reverse-the-order-of-lines-in-a-file) at stackoverflow SE
- [How to reverse lines of a text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418280/filter-to-reverse-lines-of-a-text-file) at stackoverflow SE
- [How can I print lines from file backwards (without using “tac”)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9356/how-can-i-print-lines-from-file-backwards-without-using-tac) at Unix SE

Comment: Isn't `:g/^/m0` the same as `:g/^/move 0`, which is John's answer?

Comment: @muru I think so, but this one is shorter (according to vim wikia) and I've added different explanation with few additional examples of using command lines.

Comment: Yes, I upvoted because of the other commands (I came to post `tac` as well). But I suspect the downvote was because of the answer being repeated.

Comment: I'm aware that `tac` was mentioned by OP, but all other similar questions would be duplicate of this anyway, so it's good to mentioned it again. John took this cmd from @tommcdo comment, I've taken it initially from [DerMike](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8312402/55075), but I think he taken it simply from wikia, so I've gave credits to vim wikia, so it's not completely duplicate as the explanation is completely different.

Comment: It adds more value, as it's much shorter version with proper explanation and I'm also crediting the right sources. Using shell commands is very simple and convenient. If people don't agree, they can simply down-vote, no big deal.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I'm not sure what value was adding info about `-n`, `-b`, `-c` parameters if they were not used in examples. It's only more confusing. I don't understand the point of it.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Please note that John's main answer looks like `:g/^/exe "normal ddggP"`, and it's not obvious for `:g/^/m0`, and usually if I see something like that in the first paragraph, I'm going to the next answer, as it's discouraging.

Comment: The `-r` option causes the input to be displayed in reverse order, by line. So you meant something else I think.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Example doesn't use any of `-b`, `-c` and `-n` options, so there is no point of mentioning it, as it's just simple line reversal. They can look in `man tail` if they require.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I couldn't edit John's answer as it's not a simple change and I'd have to change too many things, so it would be against author intention.

Answer (score 6):

In the spirit of functional VimL:

```
:call setline(1, reverse(getline(1, line('$'))))
```

- `getline(1, line('$'))` returns a list of all the lines in the buffer.  `'$'` is a special argument for `line()` which indicates the last line in the buffer.
- `reverse(...)` reverses the input list, in-place.  One would need to use `reverse(copy(...))` if the input list shouldn't be modified.
- `setline(1, ...)` replaces the specified line with the second argument.  When the second argument is a list, the same number of lines as the length of the list is replaced with the content of the list.

If you like, you can also define a command which takes a range (default `%` entire buffer)

```
:command! -bar -range=% Reverse call setline(<line1>, reverse(getline(<line1>, <line2>)))
```

Comment: I like this answer. It also doesn't highlight stuff (if `hlsearch` is enabled) like the `:g/` command from the other answers... Performance is perhaps worse, though? Since it `getline(1, line('$'))` gets the entire buffer in memory. `reverse()` seems to be in-place, so that should take very little memory as such...

Answer (score 5):

Per the Vim Documentation [usr_12.txt - Clever Tricks](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_12.txt.html#12.4)

> #### 12.4 Reverse line order
>
> The `:global` command can be combined with the `:move` command to move
>   all the lines before the first line, resulting in a reversed file. 
>   The command is:
>
> ```
> :global/^/m 0
> ```
>
> Abbreviated:
>
> ```
> :g/^/m 0
> ```
>
> The `^` regular expression matches the beginning of the line (even if
>   the line is blank).  The `:move` command moves the matching line to
>   after the mythical zeroth line, so the current matching line becomes
>   the first line of the file. As the `:global` command is not confused
>   by the changing line numbering, `:global` proceeds to match all
>   remaining lines of the file and puts each as the first.
>
> This also works on a range of lines.  First move to above the first
>   line and mark it with `mt`.  Then move the cursor to the last line in
>   the range and type:
>
> ```
> :'t+1,.g/^/m 't
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Using relative numbers. Paragraph starts at line 13 and spams more 4 lines

```
 :13,13+4g/^/m12
```